# Django many-to-many query for zero records in related model

Tags: django-models

Using the standard Django example model for M2M relationships.  I would like to return a list of `Person` (people) that don't have a `Membership` (ie. no related records in the `Membership` table.  How would I go about doing this?  Is anybody able to point me in the right direction?

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
Person.objects.filter(membership__isnull=True)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#isnull